# How to calculate TAX column from SAL column?

Tags: oracle

I have salary and tax columns in a table. I need to automatically put conditional values in `tax` column, calculated by `sal` column. So if I changed values in salary, the tax changew automatically. For example:
if the salary more than 3000 make the `tax = salary*25/100` etc

How can I do it?

And how to add column in the middle of the table ?

```
EMPNO                  
ENAME                 
JOB                 
MGR                 
HIREDATE                 
SAL                 
COMM                 
DEPTNO                 
TAX    <-- don't want here
```

Comment: A trigger could do this.

Comment: Okay, so technically this is two questions not one, but the main question is a focused programming issue. So this shouldn't have been closed as "Too Broad"

Answer (score 1):

> "i need to put automatically values by a condition in tax column will be calculated by salary column so if i changed values in salary, the tax change automatically."

Since 11g the easiest way to do this is with a virtual column:

```
alter table emp add tax number generated always as (sal * 0.25);
```

This will automatically maintain the value of `tax` whenever `sal` is populated.

> "need to put more than condition...mean for example (more than 4000 have 25% and more than 3000 have 20%, etc"

So the problem with this approach is that it doesn't *easily* allow you to vary the tax rate for different employees by salary band. We can do it,  say with a CASE statement ...

```
alter table emp add tax number generated always as 
    (case when sal < 3000 then 0 when sal < 4000 then sal * 0.2 else sal * 0.25 end );
```

... but this is messy.

Also it is bad practice to embed these sort of business rules in the physical data model. For one they are lack visibility in our database tools, so they are easy to overlook when diagnosing bugs or conducting impact assessment.

But the bigger issue is that business rules change. So if the tax rates change we have to apply the changes by modifying the column so the new rates will ripple backwards in time, which would worry everybody. For things like tax, it's probably better to calculate it programmatically on demand, which will allow you to control the calculations more accurately.

And that means a trigger.

```
alter table emp add tax number;

create or replace trigger emp_tax_calc
     before insert or update on emp
     for each row
begin
    case 
        when :new.sal  < 3000 then :new.tax := 0;
        when :new.sal  < 4000 then :new.tax := :new.sal * 0.20;
        else :new.tax := :new.sal * 0.25;
    end case;
end;
/
```

Here is [a LiveSQL demo (free Oracle Technet account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gf82aft3lpdfksdhz9sluv3hl).

---

> "how to add column in the middle of the table"

This you can't do. Columns added to existing tables are appended to the end of the projection. This makes perfect sense if you think about the effort involved in shuffling table that would be required to squeeze a new column into the middle of a table.

But the order of a table's columns doesn't really matter. All that counts is the order in which they appear in a SELECT projection. It's (almost) always better to explicitly list columns rather than rely on `select *`, so you have the ability to arrange the projected columns in any order you desire.

Comment: thanks too much for reply but i need to put more than condition... the tax changes ...mean for example (more than 4000 have 25% and more than 3000 have 20%, etc)

Comment: first,i need to say big thanks to u for ur interesting with reply my question... second, i know this is messy lol.. but i still in learning time so i need to know how to do every thing inside the business rules and outside , it is so cool

Answer (score 0):

As [@APC stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49451826/1509264), the simplest method is a virtual column:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/099103/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE emp( sal NUMBER );

ALTER TABLE emp ADD tax NUMBER
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      GREATEST( 0, sal -    0 ) * 0.00 --               0% tax on salary >= 0
    + GREATEST( 0, sal - 3000 ) * 0.20 -- + additional 20% tax on salary >= 3000
    + GREATEST( 0, sal - 4000 ) * 0.05 -- + additional  5% tax on salary >= 4000
  );

INSERT INTO emp (sal) VALUES ( 0 );
INSERT INTO emp (sal) VALUES ( 3000 );
INSERT INTO emp (sal) VALUES ( 3500 );
INSERT INTO emp (sal) VALUES ( 4000 );
INSERT INTO emp (sal) VALUES ( 5000 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM emp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/099103/1/0)**:

```
|  SAL | TAX |
|------|-----|
|    0 |   0 |
| 3000 |   0 |
| 3500 | 100 |
| 4000 | 200 |
| 5000 | 450 |
```